# Org-superstar-mode not enabled from config file

Tags: org-mode, package

I'm just getting started with emacs, and I'm trying to enable org-superstar-mode automatically upon launching an org file. I've installed org-superstar, and I can run M-x org-superstar-mode when in an org file to set it manually.
However, I have the following in my .emacs:

```
(use-package org-superstar
  :config
  (setq org-superstar-special-todo-items t)
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                             (org-superstar-mode 1))))
```

and my org files still do not load org-superstar-mode by default, need to do it manually. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of 'org-superstar-mode 1'? Or have I made an error?

EDIT: I'm not sure what exactly was going wrong, but I ended up just cleaning out my .emacs file and starting from scratch. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just cleaning out my .emacs folder, undownloading everything from melpa, and starting from scratch. Kept a close eye on git documentation instructions, and proceeded with care. Good luck everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting `use-package-always-defer` to `t`, If that the config code won't be executed.
Try:

```lisp
(use-package org-superstar
  :after org
  :hook (org-mode . org-superstar-mode)
  :config
  (setq org-superstar-special-todo-items t))
```

or

```lisp
(use-package org-superstar
  :init
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-superstar-mode)
  :config
  (setq org-superstar-special-todo-items t))
```

Comment: No luck with either of those, and no I am not setting use-package-always-defer